# AS3, Animation appearing correctly but causing "ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label idleForwards not found in scene idleForwards."

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently making a game in AS3 and my main character has animations for walking left, right, down and up and these play just fine error free, however when I hold down two keys at the same time the right animation will play but the terminal will output:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label idleForwards not found in scene idleForwards.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at worldOfTheAngeistyDeity_fla::MainTimeline/handleKeyRelease()
```

The code associated with playing the movement animations is:

```
***if (wPressed || wPressed && dPressed) {
        playersChar.gotoAndStop("walkBack");
    } else if (aPressed || aPressed && wPressed) {
        playersChar.gotoAndStop("walkLeft");
    } else if (sPressed || sPressed && aPressed) {
        playersChar.gotoAndStop("walkForwards");
    } else if (dPressed || dPressed && sPressed) {
        playersChar.gotoAndStop("walkRight");
    }***
```

I've checked all the named frames and they are being called correctly but I'm just not sure if there is a simple error I'm missing or if I'm going about this the wrong way, any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem code is not on the provided piece. It should be something like **gotoAndStop("idleForwards", "idleForwards");**

Comment: @Daniel does this logic work for first IF line without errors: `if( (wPressed && dPressed) || wPressed ) { playersChar.gotoAndStop("walkBack"); }`